# Join condition in mysql need to ignore null field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: post, post_image

I am currently trying to join them like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT post.*, post_image.name AS img FROM post, post_image 
WHERE post_image.postId=post.id LIMIT 10';
```

Here's my problem. Some posts do not have any entries in post_image, but I still need them returned as well. I know that mysql can check for null, but I'm not sure where it would go in my statement if that is the solution. I'm also not entirely sure I can do this with the shorthand join I am using.

Please help :)

Edit:

This is working as expected now, but I also need to make sure that it only pulls the post_image with field ordinal=0 as there can be multiple post_image entries. I tried adding a WHERE clause and it seemed to only pull posts with images.Here's what I have:

```
SELECT post.*, post_image.name AS img FROM post LEFT JOIN post_image ON post_image.postId=post.id WHERE post_image.ordinal=0 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I solved that part by adding an AND to the JOIN instead of WHERE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT 
  post.*, 
  post_image.name AS img 
FROM post
LEFT JOIN post_image ON post_image.postId = post.id 
LIMIT 10;
```

Your query is `INNER JOIN` the two tables using the old join syntax which uses the `WHERE` clause to specify the join condition. Better off use the explicit `JOIN` syntax using the `INNER JOIN` condition instead in future queries.

For more information:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- [**Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @Helto - Move this condition to the `ON` clause not in the `WHERE` like this : `... ON post_image.postId = post.id AND post_image.ordinal = 0 LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 1):

How about using `LEFT JOIN`? I think it will show the post although it does not have image.

```
SELECT * FROM post p LEFT JOIN post_image pi ON p.id = pi.postId
```